# Does typescript not understand loose equality and strict equality?

Tags: typescript

Error I am receiving:

This condition will always return 'true' since the types 'string' and 'number' have no overlap.

code:

```
if (this.$route.params.groupId != this.group.id) {
      more code here
 }
```

'1' != 1 (would return false)

'1' !== 1 (would return true)

It will not always return true

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26592

Comment: @IngoBürk please share it as an answer

Comment: Yeah, it's just a poor error *message*; it is intentionally an error (see [microsoft/TypeScript#30655](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30655)) but the error message should be something like `Operator '!=' cannot be applied to types 'string' and 'number'`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your to clarify why typescript shows that error ( that comes from typescript show error message ) https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26592

In my opinion, we can determine the type for the variable to compare it correctly

```js
use `===` or `!==` to compare value
```

```js
Determine of type variable
const routeGroupId: string = this.$route.params.groupId;
const currentGroupId: string = this.group.id;
if(routeGroupId != currentGroupId)
```